# Carpeta con información personal en Git

Tags: git, github, rutas, visual-studio-2022

Tengo conocimientos muy básicos en Git. Desde **Visual Studio 2022** coloqué como **Local path: C:\Users\Usuario**, lo cual me “inició” un repositorio con toda mi información personal. Imagen de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fuente: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/version-control/git-create-repository?view=vs-2022

Ejemplos de la terminal:

```
    PS C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Proyectos CRUD\PROYECTO PROGRAMACIÓN III\Proyecto> git status

[…]

warning: could not open directory 'Plantillas/': Permission denied

warning: could not open directory 'Reciente/': Permission denied

warning: could not open directory 'SendTo/': Permission denied

On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:

  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        ../../../../.android/

        ../../../../.azuredatastudio/

        ../../../../.bash_history

[…]

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

PS C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Proyectos CRUD\PROYECTO PROGRAMACIÓN III\Proyecto> git remote -v

origin  https://github.com/user/Gestion.git (fetch)

origin  https://github.com/user/Gestion.git (push)
```

Por otra parte, de esta manera (Eliminar) se borran carpetan en mi pc:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### ¿Qué debería hacer para no dañar nada en mi pc?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! borra la carpeta .git, y empeza de vuelta.. no borres nada de tu pc...

Comment: En esa misma carpeta se debió haber creado una carpeta `.git`. Así que borrala y listo. Normalmente está oculta.